Ping Federate - How to fix Unable to proxy SSO request: Failed to send PAR request to 'https://xxx:9031/as/par.oauth2'?
I'm trying to setup an openid connect SSO. When trying to connect, I get this error:
2024-12-19 13:29:53,433 tid:h-Ybvi6bU6lRR4rdLQjnIbJO1qM ERROR [org.sourceid.websso.profiles.ExceptionLoggingSupport] Exception occurred during request processing
org.sourceid.websso.profiles.RequestProcessingException: Unable to proxy SSO request: Failed to send PAR request to 'https://xxxx:9031/as/par.oauth2'
        at org.sourceid.oauth20.handlers.OAuthResumableRequestHandlerBase.resumeUserAuthn(OAuthResumableRequestHandlerBase.java:783) ~[pf-protocolengine.jar:?

The SSL certificate is valid and is NOT self-signed.
The endpoint is working with no issue when calling it directly though. I can provide more logs or config details if needed.
I have no idea where this idea could come from. Does anyone have a solution please?
